# match the view to the screen size-android

Tags: android, screen

When I run my application on small screen, the edit text Is out of the screen. 
I mean when writing something, it writes some char and I can't see it and only after 9-10 chars I see what I type.

How can I fix it so it will match all sizes of screen?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="צריכת חשמל"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <View android:layout_height="12dip" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/songs_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:prompt="@string/products"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="מוצר"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_module"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp" />

        <TextView
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="דגם"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow332"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_horse"
            android:layout_width="1sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="כוח סוס"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/radio_hot_or_cold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup_consume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radio_consume"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_message_hot"
                android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:minEms="2"
                android:minWidth="15sp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView android:text="צריכה בחום" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_message_cold"
                android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:minEms="2"
                android:minWidth="15sp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView android:text="צריכה בקור" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow44"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_watt"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="וואט"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow441"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_kotsh"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="קושט"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/duration_spinner"
            android:layout_width="1sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_mineutes"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:minEms="2"
            android:minWidth="15sp" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:text="משך הפעלה"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <View android:layout_height="12dip" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/alutbutton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="compute_hashmal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/alut_zria" />
    </TableRow>

    <View android:layout_height="25dip" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="5sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10sp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savebutton"
            android:alpha="0.95"
            android:onClick="save_hashmal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="שמור מוצר" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savedItems"
            android:alpha="0.95"
            android:onClick="goToSavedItems"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="פריטים שמורים" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: add your complete XML code. We don't find any EditText.

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: the attribute `layout_width` and `layout_height` are mandatory for each view. You have not added that. Please update your question with expected UI output. It will be easy for us